# How to make QTextTable to cover whole document width

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextdocument

I am trying to make the QTextTable inside QTextDocument to have 100% or full width of the document. But there is no method in QTextTableFormat class to format the QTextTable to have 100% width. We can resize row and column but not overall table.

Is there any way I can achieve that, if you know how, please share. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since [`QTextTableFormat`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexttableformat.html) inherits from [`QTextFrameFormat`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextframeformat.html) it also has the [`setWidth()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextframeformat.html#setWidth) method that allows you to set the width using [`QTextLength`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextlength.html) as a basis that can set the width as a percentage of the document width:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
    table = w.textCursor().insertTable(4, 5)

    fmt = table.format()
    fmt.setWidth(QtGui.QTextLength(QtGui.QTextLength.PercentageLength, 100))
    table.setFormat(fmt)

    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]